# Where to find file tag options in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, files, tagging

This link mentioned tags associated with files.
http://www.iloveubuntu.net/nautilus-receives-tags-ubuntu-1204-lts

But I cannot find it on my Linux 12.04.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont you see `Tags` tab when you right click on a file or folder and select `Properties`?

Comment: No. I cannot see it. And when I searched for this issue, some people complained the same problem.